# How to use cookie in angular js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to use cookie in angular.I already use session and local storage in javascript .could you you please tell how to to use cookies in angular I am getting "undefined" error while using angular .I learn tutorial 
https://github.com/ivpusic/angular-cookie

here is my code 
http://goo.gl/NTmqNA

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="cookies.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="cont">

    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
     var app= angular.module('app',['ipCookie'])
     function cont($scope,ipCookie){
         ipCookie("test", "testvalue
         console.log(ipCookie("test"))
     }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: There is an official ngCookies module which would probably be better to use: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies

Comment: Mean I will use ngcookies instead of ipCookie ?

Comment: I have added a full answer below

Comment: You also have a typo. The line `ipCookie("test", "testvalue` should be `ipCookie("test", "testvalue")`

Comment: @rwacarter check the latest code http://goo.gl/NyxlGM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the reference to cookies.js to https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular-cookies.js. Then your script could look something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngCookies'])

app.controller('cont', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
    // Retrieving a cookie
    var favoriteCookie = $cookies.myFavorite;
    // Setting a cookie
    $cookies.myFavorite = 'oatmeal';
}]);
```

EDIT: Alternatively, if you wanted to stick with ipCookie, something like this should work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="cookies.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="cont">

        </div>

        <script>
            var app= angular.module('app',['ipCookie'])

            app.controller("cont", function($scope,ipCookie){
                ipCookie("test", "testvalue");
                console.log(ipCookie("test"))
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @rwacartar actually some developer using the  "ipCookie".That why i am trying to use ipcookie

Comment: I want to know what is this : https://github.com/ivpusic/angular-cookie.I saw good developer code he used this

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a solution using ipCookie

Comment: The API for $cookies has changed since 1.4. Now you should use the `.get` and `.put` methods.